# How do i dump a specific subversion path from a berkeley db?

Tags: svn, berkeley-db, svnadmin

I'm trying to migrate one specific branch from a windows subversion berkeley db installation, however I cant seem to be able to work out how to pass a "path" to it as its a db structure and not a flat file system.

Can anyone give me any pointers, with preferably an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
svnadmin dump [PATH_TO_REPO] | svndumpfilter include [PATH_OF_BRANCH] > output.dmp
svnadmin create [PATH_TO_NEW_REPO]
svnadmin load [PATH_TO_NEW_REPO] < output.dmp
```

Remarks:

- [PATH_TO_REPO] and [PATH_TO_NEW_REPO] is the local Filesystempath to
  your repository, not the URL

[PATH_OF_BRANCH] is a repository relative path to your branch, *without* URL to repository, ususally something like:

```
/branches/myproject/BUGFIX_01
```

Comment: It should be "> output.dmp" to redirect the output of the dump