# How do you restore (load) a BRANCH from an Subversion Dump onto a new repository on a new server?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Given that googling showed absolutely no hits I think I know the answer to this question (which is "no you can't do that") but just to be sure...

I used svn dump to backup a subversion repository.  Now I want to do an svn load on a different server with a new install of subversion of that backup.  But the catch is...I only want to restore a specific branch not the whole repository.

Is that possible with svn load or some other tool?

I already found this SO question...

[How do i dump a specific subversion path from a berkeley db?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386141/how-do-i-dump-a-specific-subversion-path-from-a-berkeley-db)

This accomplishes the same goal (and I can definitely do that if all else fails but I am trying to save some time).  With that post you dump only what you need and then do a straight up Load.  I want to only load what I need from a full dump.

**EDIT**
Thanks for your feedback.  But I am still not getting it.

- I have a dump file located at e:\svnBackups\repoBackup.svn
- I have all of my new repos at e:\Repositories
- I want to only restore a single branch of e:\svnBackups\repoBackup.svn.
- The branch I want to restore is at productionRepo/Projects/Branches/MyCoolBranch in the backup.
- I want the new repo (on a new server) at e:\Repositories\newRepo

Using this information, what command line command do I type to make it happen?

Seth

Comment: Looking at your edit. Are you saying that you want to restore that one branch into a CURRENT that already contains the other branches, plus the trunk, and the tags?

Answer (score 0):

Um... wouldn't

```
svndumpfilter include BRANCH_PATH DUMP_FILE | svnadmin load REPOSITORY
```

do this, or am I misreading the question somehow?

Comment: Yes...you are mis-reading the question.  I have a FULL DUMP and want to only load a BRANCH.  Seth

Comment: Um, okay. But if you have a full dump, `svndumpfilter` can be used like above to filter out the revisions that don't involve the branch you want... and then that's piped into `load`, which should give you a repo with only that one branch. But if you need to load that branch as if it was `trunk`, then you'll also have to write something to rewrite the paths in the filtered dump...

Comment: OK...let me research svndumpfilter...maybe that will do it?  Seth

Comment: AKX...I have edited my question...do you think you could take a look?

Answer (score 0):

svndumpfilter will allow you to only keep that one branch just as AKX pointed out. In fact, you can do it in one go:

```
$ svnadmin dump $old_repos | svndumpfilter include $branch_path \
   | svnadmin load --force-uuid $new_repos
```

The only issue is that branch will be a branch, and you'll have no trunk or tags. Of course, you can simply rename the branch to trunk.

You might be able to use the `svnadmin load --parent-dir` to move your branch to the trunk during the load. You'll have to experiment with it.